# Unable to use Normal Devise Helper Methods with Devise_Token_Auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm unable to use devise helpers like user_signed_in? or any of the others with this gem. My stack trace and errors are below. Does anyone have a working solution? I never had this problem before. I'm working on a large project and I need to include the API in the overall app infrastructure for mobile devices. I commented out the devise auth token routes to see if they were the cause of the problem. To no avail, I am now unable to do anything with the project itself; due to being locked out of the Devise routes.

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
<% if user_signed_in? %>

devise (4.3.0) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:47:in resource_class' devise_token_auth (0.1.42) app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb:21:inset_user_by_token'
devise_token_auth (0.1.42) lib/devise_token_auth/controllers/helpers.rb:123:in current_user' devise_token_auth (0.1.42) lib/devise_token_auth/controllers/helpers.rb:119:inuser_signed_in?'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:68:in user_signed_in?' app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16:in_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___51327025_116383452'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in block in render' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:ininstrument'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:352:in instrument_render_template' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:inrender'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:64:in render_with_layout' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:inrender_template'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in render' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:inrender_template'
actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in render' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in_render_template'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in _render_template' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:inrender_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in render_to_body' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:inrender_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in render' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:inrender'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in block (2 levels) in render' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:inblock in ms'
C:/Ruby233/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in realtime' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:inms'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in block in render' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:incleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:29:in cleanup_view_runtime' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:inrender'
responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:238:in default_render' responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:170:into_html'
responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:163:in respond' responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:156:incall'
responders (2.4.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:211:in respond_with' devise (4.3.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:12:innew'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in send_action' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:inprocess_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in process_action' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:inblock in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in run_callbacks' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:inprocess_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in process_action' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:inblock in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in block in instrument' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:ininstrument'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in instrument' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:inprocess_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in process_action' activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:inprocess_action'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in process' actionview (5.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:inprocess'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in dispatch' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:indispatch'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in dispatch' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:inserve'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in block in <class:Constraints>' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:inserve'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:46:in block in serve' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:ineach'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in serve' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:832:incall'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in block in call' warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:incatch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in call' rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:incall'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in call' rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:incall'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in context' rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:incall'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in call' activerecord (5.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:incall'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in block in call' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:inrun_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in call' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:incall'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in call' web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:incall_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in block in call' web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:incatch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in call' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:incall'
railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in call_app' railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:inblock in call'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in block in tagged' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:intagged'
activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in tagged' railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:incall'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in call' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:incall'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in call' rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:incall'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in call' activesupport (5.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:incall'
actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in call' actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:incall'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in call' railties (5.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:incall'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in call' puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:600:inhandle_request'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in process_client' puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:299:inblock in run'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Application_Controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include Pundit

  class User::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
    def initialize(*)
      super
      permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :country, :state, :city_or_town, :zip_code, :how_did_you_learn_about_us])
    end
  end

  class Employer::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
    def initialize(*)
      super
      permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email, :company_name, :full_name, :contact_number, :employee_count])
    end
  end

  protected
  def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == User
      User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
    elsif resource_class == Employer
      Employer::ParameterSanitizer.new(Employer, :employer, params)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Routes.Rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount CountryStateSelect::Rails::Engine, at: "/"

  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :employers
  devise_for :users

  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'user_auth'
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'Employer', at: 'employer_auth'
    end
  end

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated do
      root to: 'user_dashboard#index', as: 'authenticated_user_root'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'home#index', as: 'unauthenticated_user_root'
    end
  end

  devise_scope :employer do
    authenticated do
      root to: 'employer_dashboard#index', as: 'authenticated_employer_root'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'home#index', as: 'unauthenticated_employer_root'
    end
  end

  devise_scope :admin do
    authenticated do
      root to: 'admin_dashboard#admin', as: 'authenticated_admin_root'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'home#index', as: 'unauthenticated_admin_root'
    end
  end
```

Application.html.erb

```
<body>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<% elsif employer_signed_in? %>
<% elsif admin_signed_in? %>
<% else %>
// Default Route
</body>
```

devise_token_auth.rb

```
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
  config.enable_standard_devise_support = true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid clashing devise_token_auth with the devise base gem. Requires containerizing your API, and keeping it away from your normal controllers.

For instance, below:

```
# controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb
module Api
  module V1
    class ApplicationController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
      include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
    end
  end
end
```

The API controller includes the DeviseTokenAuth Concerns to manage the app from within its own domain. It derives from the original ApplicationController.

Now, in the original Application Controller. You just have to verify that the API controller is being used.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, if: :verify_api

  def verify_api
    params[:controller].split('/')[0] != 'devise_token_auth'
  end
end
```

The whole idea is to redirect each flow of the application, depending on which part of the infrastructure is needed. I hope that this solution holds through. I also hope that the makers of the gem come up with a more steady approach.

Answer (score 0):

if you previously using bcrypt, make sure you delete some of these method that you created manually in application controller (current_user, login, auth) to make sure it's not conflict with the method that provided by devise.

check inside you session controller, how your process / run login user method, below is sample code to create session for login user

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      login user
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: I didn't override anything. I simply made changes to allow the new attributes for the Devise Model. I'll post my Application_Controller.rb and Routes.rb

Comment: There are no user records in my database.

Comment: Ok, my suggestion you trace the logic of your routes before it touched <% if user_signed_in? %> , you can debug with put command, and then you check rails console screen, or your can also use bye bug gem, I prefer just traditional ruby command put to trace it

Comment: I removed <% if user_signed_in? %>
<% elsif employer_signed_in? %>
<% elsif admin_signed_in? %>
<% else %> and the link to user/sign_in worked. There's definitely something clashing with it.

Comment: I found a way. I will write out the solution here.